# Disappeared personal views

Tags: 2010, list, list-view

Have you ever facing the issue with dissappearing personal views? I have a big list with a lot of columns, rows, public & personal views, but without any calculated columns, 3rd party features, workflows or complicated rights, there are only 4 AD groups. One day, some personal views vanished.

If I open SP Designer, I can see some of them with blank "Modified by" field and 0 KB size. Some of them missing at all. When I opened the visible ones (in normal or advanced more, it doesn't matter), they get back their 4 KB size and "Modified by" name, but acting like public.

[image]

If I restore the list from backup to some other SC or test mirrored farm, could I simple copy the view back? And do you have any idea what is wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Have you had any issues with user profile import or synchronisation? You may find this issue is due to not being able to map users to these views. Are users alerts still working?

Comment: @Russell working as usual, no errors except one account (of our general director) which is in a special OU in AD by purpose. Profile problems came also to my mind, but I cannot test if views are gone somewhere else, this users has personal views for this one list only